# Angle between two points

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I need to get angle between two points on the flat(x,y), for example I have points A and B, point A have directions(90), how could I count angle between points A and B from A directions in Java?

Here's an image for example:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered that tan(θ) = height of B/length of B?  I agree that this is more math.  If you're stuck on implementation, maybe you should phrase it that way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Math

Comment: This is tagged with Java.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Calculating the angle between two points in degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970281/java-calculating-the-angle-between-two-points-in-degrees)

Comment: This is a basic trigonometry problem -- really has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 4):

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.abs(pointBY - pointAY), Math.abs(pointBX - pointAX)));
```

This calls the inverse tangent function to find an angle based on the lengths of the opposite and adjacent sides of a right angled triangle. However, you should add this if statement:

```
if(!(pointAX == pointBX || pointAY == pointBY))
{
angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.abs(pointBY - pointAY), Math.abs(pointBX - pointAX)));
}
```

Otherwise you can cause an exception because the tan function breaks down if the angle is 90 or 0 degrees.

`pointAX` and `pointBX` are the X coordinates of the points, while `pointAY` and `pointBY` are the Y coordinates of the points.

This function finds the absolute value of the difference between the coordinates (so the length of the opposite and adjacent sides of the right-angled triangle formed from the two points) and then performs the inverse tan function on them, finding the angle.

Comment: Thank you, I understood, how to get angle between A and B points, but I don't understand how get angle between AB angle and A direction, here's small example what I need there is 3 points A1,A2 and B, points A has direction, image: http://cs614922.vk.me/v614922073/13f87/a3d26coYe-4.jpg

Comment: Please not that the code above is incorrect. java.lang.Math.atan does not take in two variables. The author meant to use atan2 instead.