# Java: Rotate triangle around mass center

Tags: java, geometry

Im creating method that should rotate triangle around it's mass center,
it should work, but my check shows that it doesn't. I understand that it might be not precise rotation, but still point that is mass center should remains the same after rotation of triangle.

What I did wrong?

```
    public void rotateAroundMassCenter(double grad){
    System.out.println("Starting...");

    Point initial = this.massCenter();

    Point o =this.massCenter();
    o.printPoint();
    double angle=Math.toRadians(grad);
    System.out.println();

    //formulas
    //    x' = x0+(x-x0)*cos(A)+(y0-y)*sin(alpha);
    //    y' = y0+(x-x0)*sin(A)+(y-y0)*cos(alpha);

    //new points
    int ax = (int) (o.x+(this.getA().x-o.x)*Math.cos(angle)-(this.getA().y-o.y) *Math.sin(angle));
    int ay = (int) (o.y+(this.getA().x-o.x)*Math.sin(angle)+(this.getA().y-o.y) * Math.cos(angle));
    this.a.movePoint(ax, ay);

    int bx = (int) (o.x+(this.getB().x-o.x)*Math.cos(angle)-(this.getB().y-o.y) *Math.sin(angle));
    int by = (int) (o.y+(this.getB().x-o.x)*Math.sin(angle)+(this.getB().y-o.y) * Math.cos(angle));
    this.b.movePoint(bx, by);

    int cx = (int) (o.x+(this.getC().x-o.x)*Math.cos(angle)-(this.getC().y-o.y) *Math.sin(angle));
    int cy = (int) (o.y+(this.getC().x-o.x)*Math.sin(angle)+(this.getC().y-o.y) * Math.cos(angle));
    this.c.movePoint(cx, cy);

    Point finalCenter=this.massCenter();
    System.out.println();
    finalCenter.printPoint();

    //check center position after rotate
    if (initial==finalCenter  ){
        System.out.println("Rotation was correct");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Algorytm is wrong");
    }
    this.print();
}
```

here how i find mass center:

```
// mass centre
    public Point massCenter(){
        double x = (this.getA().x+this.getB().x+this.getC().x)/3;
        double y = (this.getA().y+this.getB().y+this.getC().y)/3;
        Point o= new Point(x,y);
        return o;
    }
```

Result:

```
Ready to go
Triangle is: 
A:(1.0; 1.0)B: (3.0; 1.0)C: (1.0; 4.0)
Starting...
(1.6666666666666667;2.0)Old center
New center
(3.0;3.3333333333333335)Algorithm is wrong
Triangle is: 
A:(2.0; 1.0)B: (6.0; 3.0)C: (1.0; 6.0)
```

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260445/rotating-a-triangle-around-a-point-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very little mistake ^^

```
if (initial==finalCenter  ){...
```

that's never true, you must compare by using equal:

```
if (initial.equals(finalCenter)  ){...
```

Comment: you can also compare `initial.x == fianlCenter.x && initial.y == finalCenter.y`

Comment: Yes, my mistake, thanks. But still points aren't equal. Rotation formula seems to be right from geometrical point... It looks like triangle is moved somewhere, but not rotated.

Comment: Wonderfull, thank you! Now my check shows that points are equal. But, I still can't get how it may be)
Please see example:

     `Ready to go
      Triangle is: 
      A:(1.0; 1.0)B: (1.0; 3.0)C: (4.0; 1.0)
      Starting...
      (2.0;1.6666666666666667)Old center
      New center
      (4.0;3.3333333333333335)Rotation was correct
      Triangle is:  
      A:(2.7642977396044843; 1.4881553646890875)B:          (1.3500841772313894; 4.902368927062183)C: (7.885618083164127; 3.60947570824873)`

Comment: Points are different, but equal() says that they are the same one, how can it be?